# Parse file to .aliasrc

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed, command-line

I want to transform a string given in this form:

```
xyx some commands
```

into this form:

```
alias xyz="some commands"
```

I tried different combinations in the terminal. It seems (i'm not sure) that it worked once, but never when i run this from the script. I've read somewhere that this is a variable problem.

Alias for readability:

```
alias first="sed 's/\s.*//'" 
alias rest="sed 's/\S*\s*//'"

cat  f_in | tee -a >(one=$(first)) >(two=$(rest)) | tee >(awk '{print "alias "$1"=\""$2"\""}' > f_out )
```

I used `awk` in this way to parse "`cat f_in`" into "`print`". It doesn't work. Then, i used "`awk -v`" but it still doesn't work too. How to redirect variable `$one` and `$two` into awk:

{`one=$(first)` === `first | read -r one` }?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're trying to do:

```
$ echo 'xyx some commands' |
awk '{var=$1; sub(/^[^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+/,""); printf "alias %s=\"%s\"\n", var, $0}'
alias xyx="some commands"

$ echo 'xyx some commands' |
sed 's/\([^[:space:]]*\)[[:space:]]*\(.*\)/alias \1="\2"/'
alias xyx="some commands"
```